# I'm getting No provider for RouterOutletMap using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I’m confused on how to implement routing for angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10, using @angular/router 3.0.0-beta.2. I’m getting an error No provider for RouterOutletMap, any help would be very much appreciated.

My code is:

#### app/app.component.html

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

#### app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [RegistrationComponent, WelcomeComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, appRoutingProviders]
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

#### app/app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component'

 const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
   { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent }
 ]

 export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

 ];

 export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

#### main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { appRoutingProviders } from './app/app.routes';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, appRoutingProviders]);
```

#### EXCEPTION

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in
>   http://localhost:4200/app/app.component.html:1:2 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION:
>   No provider for RouterOutletMap! ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: DI
>   Exception
>       at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:43:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:80:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:786:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:814:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:777:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:586:21)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:30:48)
>       at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.createInternal (AppComponent.template.js:27:70)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:96:21)
>   ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this router version is supposed to work with Angular2 versions before RC.5

In RC.5 this would look like

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ routing ],
  ...
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ],
})
```

For more details see

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html

Comment: As i'm using the cli I tried to upgrade using npm install angular-cli @angular/tsc-wrapped --save-dev (npm 3.10.6). This gave a lot of dependency errors, so looks like this isn't ready to use yet

Comment: I replaced my project dependencies with those listed in the quick start, ran _npm install_ and I'm up and running :-)

Comment: Do you know a solution for the latest version of angular cli? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107861/angular-2-no-provider-for-routeroutletmap-when-lazy-loading/40108027?noredirect=1#comment67487321_40108027

Comment: Sorry, not my area of expertise but I'm sure others will answer.

Comment: Doubt it :| I'm completely stuck in development till I can get this to work.. So frustrating