# Angular 2 how to define lazy loaded child routes of a parent route that's also lazy loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get lazy loading to work for my app but it's one issue after another. I've gotten the main route to lazy load which is `/admin`, now I want to add another route which is `/admin/login`.

So I did this:

**admin-router.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminAreaComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'login',
            loadChildren: 'app/+admin-area/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule'
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminAreaComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminAreaRouterModule {}
```

**login-router.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

// Global modules
import {ComponentsModule, SharedModule} from '../../shared';

// Components
import {LoginComponent} from '../login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class LoginRouterModule {}
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {ComponentsModule, SharedModule} from '../../../shared';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {LoginRouterModule} from './router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    LoginRouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    LoginRouterModule
  ]
})

export class LoginModule {}
```

The problem though is that as soon as I add the `children` part, `/admin` stops working all together, throwing the error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'`.

Is this not how you define child routes of a lazy loaded route? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at my repo from my previous answer to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40121008/146656

In my sample it's `lazy/deep`, which matches `admin/login` for you.

First, I ran `ng g module lazy/Deep --routing`

Then, inside `src/app/lazy/deep/deep-routing.module.ts`, I modified `routes` to:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeepComponent
  }
];
```

Then I added a `<router-outlet>` to the view of the main component in `/lazy`, so that content from `/lazy/deep` can be rendered inside it.

The important piece is how I modified the routing for `lazy-routing.module.ts`, to allow for lazy-loading the `lazy/deep` route:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LazyComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'deep',
    // Loading by relative path didn't seem to work here
    // loadChildren: './deep/deep.module#DeepModule'
    loadChildren: 'app/lazy/deep/deep.module#DeepModule'
  }
];
```

If you are running `ng watch` / `npm start` or `ng build --watch`, you'll need to restart that in order to make it work.

See the full example in `deep-lazy-loading` branch in https://github.com/Meligy/routing-angular-cli/tree/deep-lazy-loading

Comment: I was using the wrong syntax for lazy loaded child routes, they should really add some info to the docs about this cuz it is far from obvious. Big thanks again.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131110/how-to-render-a-grandchild-view-into-the-same-router-outlet-as-the-first-child

Comment: @Meligy have you tried if your example works with deep-linking, I mean as in *type/copy a link to a lazy nested route in browser address bar and press enter*?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an empty route within your LoginModule.

**login.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild({ path: '', component: LoginComponent })
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ]
})

export class LoginModule {}
```

Comment: Why do you export `RouterModule` in your modules? I'm pretty sure you shouldn't do that

Comment: Please read the documentation on the Angular 2 router. There should be no such thing as a `LoginRouterModule`. The LoginModule is the only module you should have for login. Inside that, you should define the `RouterModule.forChild`

Comment: If you read the styleguide you can see that you should have a router-module file for your routing instead of just throwing it inside the main module. Anyway I got it working now thanks to Meligy's example repo, turns out you can't use the `children` syntax with lazy loaded routes. Thanks for the pointer though :)